# increment value in JS object depending on key

Tags: javascript

I have a pretty simple setup like this:

```
var itemsPerAssignee = {}
```

My plan is to save the *amount* of items in this object, so I can later iterate over it and, depending on the key, output the specific value on how many items are left for that specific user.

In my for-loop I iterate like this, to fill the object:

```
query.forEach(function (task) {
    var assignee = task.getAssignee();
    itemsPerAssignee[assignee] = {count: 0}
}
```

this at least doesn't yield an error, but my output doesn't seem to update. So I basically would need to check, if there is a value already existing for that specific key. If so, I need to increment it by 1.

I know I could have a function to check that specific index of the object, read the value, adjust and write it. But that doesn't seem clean. I'm pretty sure there is an easier way to do so, but I don't know how.

I also fiddled around with something like:

```
itemsPerAssignee = {user: assignee, count: 0}
```

but I got stuck there and I don't know if my approach was correct.

Also, right now, I have objects with the same key multiple times, which might be part of the problem. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```js
var itemsPerAssignee = {};
var users = ["user@user.com, anotheruser@another.com", "user@user.com"];

for(u in users) {
    itemsPerAssignee[u] = {count: 0};
}

for(i in itemsPerAssignee) {
    console.log(itemsPerAssignee[i].count);
}
```

Comment: I assume `count` should be at least `1`, since the user has a task associated to them?

Comment: exactly @HaoWu - should have made that clearer, but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if exists, then create or update

```
 if(itemsPerAssignee.hasOwnProperty(assignee)){
     itemsPerAssignee[assignee].count++;
 }else{
     itemsPerAssignee[assignee] = {count: 1};
 }
```

If assignee is an actual value (like an id or email, a unique key) and not an object...

Comment: well, shows how easy it can be.. thank you. 
Will accept as soon as I'm allowed to. Thank you

Comment: `= {count: 1};` No? since you have an else

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment):

```
itemsPerAssignee[assignee] ??= { count: 0 }; // initialise if not present
itemsPerAssignee[assignee].count++; // update
```

Comment: havn't heard of that before, but that looks promising. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with one line:

```
(itemsPerAssignee[assignee] ??= { count: 0 }).count++;
```

Comment: Interesting. I always did it in [two steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77824877/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan i hope you liked it

Comment: Saves a line, makes it a little less readable for others

Comment: @mplungjan more performant though since you don't need to access the same property twice

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and giggles, here's an one-liner solution using [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) which has the worst compatibility that no one should use:

```js
const users = ["user@user.com", "anotheruser@another.com", "user@user.com"];

const tasks = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(Object.groupBy(users, _ => _))
  .map(([k, { length }]) => [k, { count: length }])
);

console.log(tasks);
```